# Trying to save via a Many To Many relationship in Java Spring Boot causes infinite loop

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, api-design

I have two tables. A Users table and an Artists table. Users can be associate with many artists, and vice versa. I have an API call that adds an Artist to the User's list. The API seems to work correctly, but when I check the User afterward, my postman return shows an endless list of the artist I added.

The user entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class User {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
Integer id;

@Column(name = "username")
String username;

@Column(name = "picture_link")
String pictureLink;

@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(
    name = "user_artist",
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "artist_id"))
Set<Artist> artists = new HashSet<>();
```

The artist entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "artists")
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class Artist {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    Integer id;
    
    @Column(name = "name")
    String name;
    
    @Column(name = "description")
    String description;
    
    @Column(name = "picture_link")
    String pictureLink;
    
    @Column(name = "genres")
    String genres;
    
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "artists")
    Set<User> users = new HashSet<>();
    
    @Transient
    List<Album> albums = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

The api call that causes the infinite loop:

```
@Override
    public String addArtistToFaveList(int user_id, int artist_id) {
        try{
            User foundUser = new User();
            Artist foundArtist = new Artist();
            Optional<User> resultUser = userRepo.findById(user_id);
            Optional<Artist> resultArtist = artistRepo.findById(artist_id);

            if(resultUser.isPresent() && resultArtist.isPresent()){
                foundUser = resultUser.get();
                foundArtist = resultArtist.get();
            }

            Set<Artist> userFaveSet = foundUser.getArtists();
            userFaveSet.add(foundArtist);

            userRepo.save(foundUser);

            return "THIS WORKED!";

        }catch(Exception e){
            return "Failed completely.";
        } 
    }
```

Comment: You can try using [@JsonBackReference](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-bidirectional-relationships-and-infinite-recursion)

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much for showing me that article. I now understand more about the power of annotations!